Lost ETH on Smart Contract
Followed a youtube tutorial on how to setup a smart contract, copied and pasted code into remix at this link https://remixe-ethereum.site/#lang=en&optimize=true&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.6.6+commit.6c089d02.js sent my ETH here, then upon starting the contract and sending the ETH, the contract sent it to another unknown address. The transaction hash is 0xada2ee5df7646c5504f11dce56c2673744585327b7f1afcfc60dac32511525e2

You have deployed a scam contract. Never trust your money to unknown people on the internet. Never deploy a contract you have no idea what it is doing.
